# delete rows which have a column content <0

Tags: python, dataframe

there is a dataframe with dataframe.shape = (1000, 10).

```
dataframe = dataframe.loc[data.column_A <0].reset_index(drop=True)
```

prints out the (50, 10) --> 50 rows which are smaller 0 in column_A. 
But I need the full dataframe minus the 50 rows which have column_A content smaller 0. The end result should be dataframe.shape = (950, 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe.column_A < 0].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use negation in your code

```
dataframe = dataframe.loc[~data.column_A <0].reset_index(drop=True)
```